# Insert an item in a list of the same type as this item and increase a new list of other type within this item

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization

I'm having some problens working with a list in C#.

I have this class Local

```
[XmlType("Local")]
[XmlRoot("Local")]
public class clsLocal
{
    public clsLocal()
    {
       clsLocal local = new clsLocal();
    }


    [XmlElement("TypeCommunication")]
    public ETypeCommunication TypeCommunication{ get; set; }

    [XmlArray("DeviceList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Device")]
    public DeviceList ListOfDevices{ get; set; }

}
```

And i have this class to serialize this local.

```
public void SerializarXML(string path)
{
    project = new clsProject();
    local = new clsLocal();
    project .ListOfLocals.Add(new clsLocal(local));
    project .ListOfLocals[0].ListOfDevices.Add(new clsDevice { Name = "First" });

    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(clsProjeto));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(diretorio);
    s.Serialize(writer, projeto);
    writer.Close();
}
```

And that's my project class

```
 [XmlType(TypeName = "Project")]
 public class clsProject
 {
    [XmlElement("StopBits")]
    public StopBits StopBits{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DataBits")]
    public EDataBits  DataBits{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Port")]
    public EPort Port{ get; set; }

    public Parity Parity{ get; set; }

    public EBaudRatea baudRate;

    [XmlElement("BaudRate")]
    public EBaudRate BaudRate
    {
        get { return baudRate; }
        set { baudRate = value; }
    }

    [XmlArray("ListOfLocals")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Local")]
    public LocalList ListOfLocals;

}
```

I have two classes to help during serialization they are LocalList and DeviceList. Both classes only inherit from clsLocal and clsDevice.

The problem is this, my application is caught in a loop because of clsLocal instance in the constructor of clsLocal class. And I have no ideia about how I will solve this, can someone help me? :P

About the XML, He should be:

```
<Project>
 <Local>
    <Local>
       <Device>
           -First
       </Device>
     </Local>
 </Local>
 <Local>
 </Local>
</Project>
```

Comment: this should be an empty constructor in your `public class clsLocal`
`public clsLocal()
  {
  }`

Comment: why are you creating a new instance of your class inside the constructor of said class?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When i try to let the constructor empty he asks me to instantiate clsLocal in local class. I need to have a List of Locals inside of Local.

Comment: Hey Guys, i solved my problem. I just need a instance of my Lists in the constructor. Sorry for newbie question and Thanks for your time.